# Problems reading binary file on Android

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

On Windows, I use this code to read a file:

```cpp
int Num;
AnsiString pathFich = "Mypath/Myfile.myext";
ifstream Archivo(pathFich.c_str(),ios::in|ios::binary);
      
// size (integer array 15*15)
   
for(int a=0;a<15;a++)
{
    for (int t=0;b<15;b++)
    {
        Archivo.read((char *)(&Num),sizeof(Num));  //read
        ...
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly.

But when I try to read the same file on Android, it doesn't work.

It locates the file in the correct folder on mobile, goes through the file, it does not give a reading error, but the `Num` value is always the same (`-1036302319`).

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know it is not giving a reading error? The code you have shown is not checking for a reading error. Also, what does the file actually look like to begin with? How is the file being created? What value are you expecting `Num` to contain after reading it? Are you taking endian into account? Without more specific details, it is really difficult to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Ruling out that the problem is caused by one of the first 4 questions you ask (under windows the code works perfectly). Very possibly it has to do with endian. Thank you